# Save Objects to plist file

Tags: objective-c, types, plist

I need to save a CGDDisplayModeRef to a plist file but none of the available types are good for storing CGDisplayModeRef. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saved the height, width & pixel encoding to a plist file & then used the myBestMode method found in [Quartz Display Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004234-SW1) to find a mode for the saved attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an object wrapper / container for this class and implement NSCoding for an object by writing a code for coding / decoding an valuable params for CGDDisplayModeRef. Afterward use NSKeyedArchiver / NSKeyedUnarchiver for saving / loading of your wrapper object with CGDisplayModeRef inside of it.

Comment: I did so but when I loaded the data is was in NSData form, is there a way to convert it to CGDisplayModeRef?